# Pass objects from main script to child script and return back in Python Xbee

Tags: python, file, object, xbee

I want to know whether we can pass the object from `main_file.py` to the `child.py` script without wait for completion of function. Following is the programming flow on which I am currently working:

In `main_file.py`

```
import child
def node_discovery(flag):
    if flag==0:
        <Send frame with 'ND' AT command>
        var = response of ND
        flag = 1 
    return var
def <main>:
    data = child.main()
    <data is stored in some .txt file>
```

In  `child.py`

```
import main_file
def main:
    n = 0
    add = main_file.node_discovery(n)
    <using that add do some calculation>
    return calculated_value
```

Here I want `var` from node_discovery() to be execute only once. And based on that `child.py` would execute.

**Problem**
When I execute my `main_file.py` it would wait for `child.py` to complete. But, `node_discovery()` is executed everytime, which I don't want.

Can anybody help me with that?

Comment: "A" is module and "A1","A2","A3" is function inside. Anyway "A" module is dynamic so "A1" call "A2" call "A3" function. You need create new module without "auto call". And how will be sure "which client waiting a connection" ? node_discovery() set your server "alive".

Comment: @dsgdfg I got your point. Here in my case when i am writing to .txt file it will ask objects those calculated from `child.py`. For the calculation to be started I need to pass the `var` from `node_discovery()`. But, here is the catch that `node_discovery()` must be executed only once. So how to overcome this?

Comment: based on the topmost instance : <A inside B> and <B inside A>, on B "import A ; def new_A1: pass; new_A = A(); new_A.A1 = new_A1()". "from A import * " , "from B import * "  you got 2 "main" function on your example.